# Как добавить List<T> в строку таблицы базы данных

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

Допустим, у меня есть класс `Book`, где содержатся поля `Id`, `Name` и `Author`. И есть класс `User`, у которого есть поля `List<Book> Books` и `Name`.
Как создать такую структуру в БД? Получатся две таблицы: `Book` и `User`.  Но как добавить в поле `List<Book>`? Или только создавать новую таблицу с соответствиями?

Comment: У одной книги может быть несколько авторов, задумайтесь над этим :)

Comment: Попробуйте сделать так. [Пример](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Делается это очень легко.

1) Создаем сущности:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set;}

    public virtual ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }

    public User()
    {
        Books = new List<Book>();
    }
}

public class Book
{
    public int Id {get; set;}

    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

2) Создаем класс контекста, используя его мы будем взаимодействовать с БД:

```
public class EfDbContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        // Говорим EF, что сущность User может иметь много Book. 
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(p => p.Books);
    }
}
```

3) Указываем строку подключения в файле `app.config`. Обратите внимание, что имя стоки подключения такое же как и у класса контекста, в этом случае `EF` автоматически обнаружит строку и станет ее использовать:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="EfDbContext" connectionString="Data Source=.; Initial Catalog=MyDataBase; Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

4) Используем:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var context = new EfDbContext();

    // Создаем сущности.
    var book = new Book() 
    {
        Name = "Война и Мир"
    };

    var user = new User()
    {
        Name = "Вася",
        Age = 15
    };

    // Добавляем книгу пользователю.
    user.Books.Add(book);

    // Добавлеям пользователя в контекст.
    context.Set<User>().Add(user);

    // Сохраняем изменения.
    context.SaveChanges();

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Благодарю за информацию! Насколько я понял, это Code-First подход. А как это же сделать с помощью Database-First подходом?

Comment: @РамильМухаметшин [Scaffold-DbContext](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/full-dotnet/existing-db)

Comment: @РамильМухаметшин создать сначала БД, потом сгенерировать на ее основе сущности и контекст.

Comment: @Bulson Да, я так и предполагал, спасибо за информацию!

Comment: @sp7 Если я правильно понял, то нужно в таблицу User добавить ForeignKey, который будет связан с Id в таблице Book

Comment: @РамильМухаметшин наоборот, внешний ключ должен быть создан в таблице Books.

Comment: @Рамиль Мухаметшин: Здесь показан подход code-first. Entity Framework сам создаст необходимые внешние ключи. И если посмотреть созданную таблицу в SQL Server Mаnagement Studio, то в ней будет внешний ключ.

Comment: @AK пункт 2 нужен просто для наглядности, что бы явно подчеркнуть что сущность `User` может иметь много `Book`. Понятно, что если указать `modelBuilder.Entity<User>();` `EF` разрулит все автоматически, но просто данная ситуация могла бы сбить столку.